# How can I use an offline map in my Cordova app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-plugins, onsen-ui

I'm developing an app where users can use it in areas that have no internet access, The app should store the position of the user. but the user can select a different position by using google maps. When the device become online the app should sync the data with the app server.

I'm using Cordova with Google Maps, Angular-js and onsen-ui library.

Comment: I do not think you can use Google Maps offline on any platform now.

Comment: Exactly, Google Maps API doesn't offer any way to be used offline, at the moment.